# Mouse Enter Event problem, how to manipulate images?

Tags: c#

I want to change an existing image in a single picture box to another image with the Mouse Enter event.  Need help please.

Comment: WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET client side? C# isn't much to go on.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to assign to `myPictureBox.Image` in the `MouseEnter` and, presumably, `MouseLeave` events.